# Stress test private 3rd party xml

Tags: performance, web-services, jmeter, stress-testing

I would like to find a Linux based tool that allows me to test a private 3rd party http based application. That is use a **GET** or a **POST** request and check how long it takes to get a response. I could also increase the txn per second and see the outcomes of failures and whether processing time on their end increase. I could write code to do this but I'm pretty sure there is a tool to do this already I just can't find it.

JMeter seems overly complicated for the simple task I'm trying to achieve.
Selenium seems more for testing web borwser based applications.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter is perfect for this and is simpler than it seems at first.
Here are some great getting started video tutorials
http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-tutorial-video-series

Selenium won't give you the reports you need for actual response time under load.

Regarding your comments on how to graph different results (success vs errors and TPS):
Personally I only use the graphing capabilities that BlazeMeter.com provides (I work for them) which includes the ability to graph different HTTP result codes side by side or even JMeter assertions.

I think you can get what you want using this third party plugin:
http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/

Comment: Thank you very much I have been fiddling with it and its not as bad as I thought. However I am trying to run a TPS bench test with two different url paths on the same ip. I have a default http Request with a get parameter as both paths share that get param. I have attached the throughput shapping timer  and listner for each paths. See the diagram in my original question what i would like to know is how can i have the graphs show successful vs failed request side by side for each of the two graphs as i would like them to execute at once.

Comment: And maybe a clear graph comparison between the different tps i set and what the system is able to achieve.